# How to get list of movies based on genre and language

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have stuck to get list of movies based on genre and language.

Here's my database structure:

```
    movies table
-----------------------
id | title|
----------------------
1  | ABC
2  | PQR
3  | MNC
```

```
category table
-----------------------
id | catgory  | value
----------------------
1  | language |Hindi
2  | language |Endilish
3  | genre    |Drama
4  | genre    |Action
5  | genre    |Thriller
```

```
manage table
-----------------------
id|catgory_id|movie_id
----------------------
1  |     1   |  1
2  |     3   |  1
3  |     4   |  1
4  |     2   |  2
5  |     4   |  2
```

Here's what i trying to do I want movies with Hindi language with genre of Action.

Below is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM manage 
WHERE category_id='1' AND category_id='4' 
GROUP BY movie_id
```

I was expecting result of Hindi Movies with genre of Action but it returns null result.

But when I use `OR` operator in query it returns result but with movies which has language English also but expected is language **Hindi** and Genre **Action**.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I'd suggest you have another look at the db structure. would be easier if you had a seperate table for language and for genre. You can have the language_id and genre_id in different columns in the movies table it self. Would be a very cleaner approach. The way you have it right now requires complicated sql queries

Comment: That query is invalid and should raise an error. (More recent MySQL versions will, unless in compatibility mode.) You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution that uses aggregation:

```
SELECT m.id, m.title
FROM movie m
INNER JOIN manage a   ON a.movie_id = m.id
INNER JOIN category c ON a.category_id = c.id
GROUP BY m.id, m.title
HAVING 
    MAX(c.category = 'language' AND c.value = 'Hindi') = 1
    AND MAX(c.category = 'genre' AND c.value = 'Action') = 1
```

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pFrjbuyBs4VxT1PWyG5rcP/0)** with your sample data returns:

```
| id  | title |
| --- | ----- |
| 1   | ABC   |
```

Comment: Thanks GMB it returns null

Comment: @Indrajeet: I added a DB Fiddle link to my answer... This seems to work fine with your sample data.